# GPX file: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element

Tags: xml, validation, schema, gpx

I am working with GPX files and I am parsing them with Java. I am using javax.xml.validation.Validator to make sure they conform to the GPX schema. The thing is, one of my files ends with:

```
<TopoFusion:color>ff0000</TopoFusion:color>
<TopoFusion:graph>0</TopoFusion:graph>
</gpx>
```

and this TopoFusion element is apparently not defined in the GPX schema, causing the validation to fail. However, the file is valid if I am to ignore this element. Any idea how I can overcome this problem ? I want to make it generic though, not simply ignore TopoFusion element as it can be anything there.

Hope my question is clear. Any help will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Petar

Comment: What is the question? You have a clearly invalid file (one that uses an namespace that is not part of the gpx scheme) and you want that to be valid afterall? What is the point of validating against the schema in the first place then?

Comment: Thanks Eddy. Good point. I have not made my question very clear unfortunately. The thing was, that using a Xerces SAXParser, the file turned out to be valid, and I was wondering what is the problem with my program. However, after an investigation of the GPX schema, it allows this particular element to exist in a gpx files. I had a bug in the code that is fixed now. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating the GPX schema more thoroughly, I found that these two elements at the end of the .gpx files are allowed to exist from the GPX schema. So, the problem is that I had a problem in my validation method, which is now fixed.